# Eclipse fonts and background color

Tags: eclipse, configuration, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-3.3

I have been trying to change the background color of Eclipse's windows to black and customize the font colors. There doesn't seem to be a way to do this, at least not in an obvious way. I am using version 3.3.

How do I do this or are there any plugin's that might be able to assist in doing this?

Comment: Changed the background, applied and hit done, but nothing happened. Also, restarted eclipse to see if thats what it needed but nothing happened.

Comment: Related (changing font ***size***): *[How can I change font size in Eclipse for Java text editors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922305)*

Answer (score 299, accepted):

#### To change background colour

1. Open menu *Windows → *Preferences* → *General* → *Editors* → *Text Editors*

   - Browse Appearance color options
   - Select background color options, uncheck default, change to black
   - Select background color options, uncheck default, change to colour of choice

#### To change text colours

1. Open *Java* → *Editor* → *Syntax Colouring*

   - Select element from Java
   - Change colour
   - List item

#### To change Java editor font

1. Open menu *Windows* → *Preferences* → *General* → *Appearance* → *Colors and Fonts*

   - Select *Java* → *Java Editor Text font* from list
   - Click on change and select font

Comment: Thankyou, this works well for the java editor.  I was looking for more of a blanket change though, to everything.

Comment: To make this a blanket change, you'll want to select `Basic>Text Font` instead of `Java>Java Editor Text`.  Then you'll want to restart Eclipse.  Also, make sure to reset `Java>Java Editor Text` so that it will use the new default.

Comment: But how can I change the color of a autocomplete selection, see [screenshot](http://img339.imageshack.us/img339/3539/autocomplete.jpg)

Comment: Having a dark background makes my whole experience of Eclipse so much better. Thank you---it is hard to wade thru all of Eclipse's options! +1

Comment: It's actually Windows>Preferences>General>Editors>Text Editors

Comment: The perfect for me was just to change the Windows>Preferences>General>Editors>Text Editors to  grey, so you don't need to change nothing more and its almost the same that having the blackground black

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not override the selected theme's options. As soon as I apply my selection, the themes just override whatever selection I had made and I'm back on square one. I have a dark theme that does *not* set the editor's background to black (it's gray-ish). If I set the background color to black, as soon as the editors are re-opened, they're back to whatever the theme was. Very frustrating...

Comment: If you are having trouble with Eclipse 2019 and dark theme and setting the background and having it not change: There seems to be a recent [Eclipse bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=558782). I suggest you look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59599251/eclipse-2019-black-background) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60450156/eclipse-4-14-0-changing-the-editor-background-colour) for workarounds.

Answer (score 160):

I just came across this: [Eclipse Colour Themes](http://www.eclipsecolorthemes.org/)

Install the plugin and choose from a selection of pre-defined themes, or write your own.
Just what I needed!

Comment: Just installed, downloaded, and applied a theme in like 10 mins :-)

Comment: I couldn't get the plugin itself to work, but they provide a preferences import file for each style as well, do you can install the theme without ever installing the plugin.

Comment: it's nice, but only works for java colors.. does not work on javascript/dltk/vjet

Comment: Wow, this rocks!  Is there any way to get the plug-in to modify the background of the other windows (i.e., Package Explorer, LogCat, etc.)?

Comment: @any, I have installed this through eclipse market place but theme is not showing up under General->Apprnce->Theme. I have tried choosing default but no hope. I am using Eclipse IDE for C/C++ developers
Version: Kepler Release
Build id: 20130614-0229

Answer (score 15):

Under Windows → Preferences → General → Apperance you can find a dark theme.

Answer (score 12):

Background color of views (navigator, console, tasks etc) is set according to the desktop (system) settings. On Linux/GNome I changed System/Preferences/Appeareance to change this color.

Editor colors are set chaotically by different editors, search for *background* in eclipse preferences to find different options. One easy way to get beautiful dark (and not only dark) themes is to install [Afae plugin](http://robrohan.com/projects/afae/), and then pick theme within its preferences (twilight theme is beautiful, for example) - again, eclipse prefs, Afae group. Of course this applies only when you edit with Afae.

Answer (score 5):

If you are having trouble with Eclipse 2019 and using a dark theme and setting the background and having it not change: There seems to be a recent [Eclipse bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=558782). I suggest you look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59599251/eclipse-2019-black-background) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60450156/eclipse-4-14-0-changing-the-editor-background-colour) for workarounds.

Comment: God how buggy can a software be. It is sad to watch.

Answer (score 3):

You can install eclipse theme plugin then select default.
Please visit here: http://eclipsecolorthemes.org/?view=plugin

Answer (score 2):

If you go to Windows, Preferences then select General, Editors, Text editors, you can set colors on that property page (and there's a link for setting MORE colors - General, Appearance, Colors and fonts).

That's with an Eclipse 3.3 build anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to install the plugin is from the Eclipse Marketplace. Go to Help→Eclipse Marketplace, then search for Eclipse Color Theme and install it.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows or Mac, you can find this setting under the *General* → *Editors* → *Text Editors* menu.

Answer (score 0):

... on a Mac, Preferences' is under the main 'Aptana Studio 3' menu rather than the 'Windows' menu as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

**Switch to Theme...** is also an option

[image]

Comment: This is under the right click menu!