# I want to change the color of the text editor of Eclipse easily!

Tags: eclipse

Eclipse is a default, and a background color is white, 
but many developers uses the dark color (black) and thinks whether it is used the letter color with white or green. 
I can't find tools which the color template  can change an editor color of Eclipse by a blow very much. 
Do you know featured WEB sites.?

If get possible to choose dark color among a beginning like MIFES, makes me Happy

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5053834/eclipse-ide-for-java-full-dark-theme/5349143#5349143 for editor themes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse fonts and background color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186118/eclipse-fonts-and-background-color)

Answer (score 4):

I don't fully understand your question but for changing Eclipse's editor background color just go to menu: *Window* > *Preferences*, and in the dialog go to *General* > *Text Editors*. In that form just select *Background color* from the list *Appearance color options* and use the color picker in the right to change it. For other formatting options go to *General* > *Colors and Fonts* in the same dialog.

NOTE: All these formatting changes are saved in your workspace if you create a new one it'll start with the default settings

Answer (score 2):

As a very late follow-up (just found this via search), there is now Eclipse Color Theme, a plugin you can grab from the marketplace. It enables you to use color themes [from various sites](http://www.eclipsecolorthemes.org/) and load them directly.

They even got a few relatively close Netbeans-lookalikes (that's why I was looking for one).

Answer (score 0):

If you mean "themes" as Netbeans has "Dark pastels" theme - then Eclipse currently doesn't have this feature.

Comment: FYI: This is a big part of eclipse 4.0 (aka "e4"), which looks like 2010 release

Answer (score 0):

In the newer version of eclipse, we have an option **Switch to Theme...**

[image]

This should resolve the issue.