# eclipse line color background

Tags: eclipse, colors, background

In Eclipse, I try to change the background color of my comments in Java code. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to change the background colour for only comments. There is a 9 year old [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=6712) related to this so don't hold your breath waiting for a fix!!

Comment: snif...
Maybe with a plugin ?

Comment: Maybe. You might be better asking on a more Eclipse focussed forum or mailing list.

Answer (score -1):

Of course you can:
Window > Preferences
Then look for Java > Editor > Syntax Coloring 
In there you can set the style (bold, italic, color, ...) for single-line, multi-line, and javadoc comments (as well as all other syntactic markup).

*Edit:* Oh sorry, I didn't read the question well enough, as the above only works for foreground coloring.

Changing background colors in Eclipse in general is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186118/eclipse-fonts-and-background-color).

Comment: It's a solution to change the background color for all lines but I need to chnage the background color only for comments.