# How to change background color in eclipse for a not defined region?

Tags: eclipse

Really annoyed by eclipse masking over #if defined region with grey color. I want to either turn off this feature, or make it the same as for normal region. Have been looking for a solution for some time but couldn't find anything.

HELP!

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186118/eclipse-fonts-and-background-color refer this

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can adjust language syntax coloring via

> Window > Preference > [Your Language] > Editor > Syntax Coloring

for the language specified background color, you can check

> Window > Preference > Appearance > Colors and Fonts

Inside the panel, you should able to find out preference color/font for your language.

**UPDATE** :

There is an "Appearance Color Option" in

> Window > Preference > [Your Language] > Editor

For C/C++ editor, it has an option call "Inactive code highlight".

Comment: I went through those settings number of times, but couldn't find background change option for #define / #ifdef / #ifndef. I am using c++ language btw.

Comment: @Code_So1dier > I think I found what you need, check my updated answer please.

Answer (score 2):

On Mac:

1. Eclipse
2. Preferences
3. C/C++
4. Editor
5. Inactive code highlight (2nd option)