# Eclipse color theme for python like in TextMate2

Tags: python, eclipse, textmate

I'm switching from TextMate2 to Eclipse to use python. I want to have the same the color theme as for TextMate2 for python. Is there any color theme for that for Eclipse Color Theme plugin? Because I checked the website and couldn't find one. Also I don't know how to create one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Specify a color theme just for python in Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22125967/specify-a-color-theme-just-for-python-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

After you install [pydev](http://pydev.org/) (the plugin for pasing python code) in eclipse,  you can change its colors and appearance to your liking. see this [link](http://pydev.org/manual_adv_editor_prefs.html):

> In window > preferences > PyDev > editor, PyDev can edit the tab
>   settings and appearance colors used in PyDev  (such as the code color,
>   decorators, numbers, strings, comments, etc).

pydev is great btw. My favorite python IDE.

Comment: but how to change the background color?

Comment: here is the first hit on the google query "change backgroud color eclipse"... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186118/eclipse-fonts-and-background-color

Comment: but that would change the bgcolor for ALL the editors, including Java!

Comment: here is the next paragraph in the link after what I pasted here : `It's important to have in mind that many preferences, such as print margin, show line number, background/foreground colors, etc. are inherited from the text-editor preferences at general > editors > text editors, and some other preferences are at general > appearance > colors and fonts – there's a link for both at the end of the preferences page.`