# Eclipse c++ Change Compiler Color

Tags: c++, eclipse, colors

I have a dark eclipse theme and I compile c++ datas sometimes. 
Now I have the problem, that the Compiler outputs his text in black on black background and i didnt find the option to change this.

Do somebody know how i can change it?

Comment: Did you see this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186118/eclipse-fonts-and-background-color ?

Comment: the normal text font is changed. I need to change the font of the compiler.

Comment: Try Preferences -> Appearance -> Colors and Fonts -> C/C++ and change console text.

Comment: There I just can change the size and the type of the text

Comment: Did you figured it out ? I would like to change the highlight color...