# Eclipse Text Editor background color seems to be overwritten by the current theme

Tags: eclipse

I'm using a Cobalt theme (from GEdit) for the text editor, but the background isn't as it should be. When i try to change it (Generel->Editors->Text Editors : Background Color), it has no effect, the background color stays grey (supposed to be blue).

[image: Preferences]

[image: Random line preview]

As you can see, the background stays grey (should be the same background of the margin), maybe overwritten by Eclipse's Dark Theme ?

Comment: Do you need help reporting it to Eclipse or what is your question?

Comment: I'm not sure, am i not understanding how to change the background, is this behavior normal ?

Comment: It seems to be a bug, as it works in the default light theme. If you want it fixed, at least make sure it has been reported.

Comment: Has this been reported to Eclipse? If so, what is the bug number?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Eclipse 2019 black background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59599251/eclipse-2019-black-background)