# Eclipse (4.14.0), changing the editor background colour

Tags: eclipse

I had set the theme to Dark, and changed the editor background/foreground colours, but it did not work (only changed the line number background). So, I searched the web and found [the existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186118/eclipse-fonts-and-background-color). But the answer was saying the same thing that I already had done.

Is the method changed? Why can't I set the editor background to complete black and the text to complete white?

[image]

Comment: As far as I know, this is a known bug of the dark theme of Eclipse 4.14. Please check if it has been fixed in the [current milestone build](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2020-03/m2). Please note, that a complete black background is not eye friendly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Eclipse 2019 black background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59599251/eclipse-2019-black-background)

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:
1. Launch Eclipse
2. Click on Help
3. Select Eclipse Marketplace
4. Open Popular tab
5. Select and install "Darkest Dark Theme with DevStyle CI 2019.9.16"
6. Wait for it to finish installation
7. Restart Eclipse
At this stage, eclipse should restart with options to tweak background colour to your desired theme

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a recent [Eclipse bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=558782).

There is a possibly duplicate question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59599251/eclipse-2019-black-background) which has at least one additional suggested workaround besides the other answer to this question.

Comment: This bug still exists 4.28.0. Interestingly, if you change the background color in General -> Editors -> Text Editors under Appearance color options, it will actually change the background when you hit "Apply", then it will change back once you close the dialog window.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still looking for this **known** bug in eclipse -> install the plugin that James Kufre mentioned, right know there is another version called:
*Darkest Dark Theme with DevStyle 2022.6.13a*.
This plugin fixes the bug. You can then basically choose the complete color scheme of eclipse. So not only the editor field, but also the menus and everything!